# how can I use web forms Response.redirect with angular 6 routing?

Tags: asp.net, angular, webforms, angular2-routing, url-routing

I have added an angular 6 app into a master page in a web forms project.

```
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

In web forms master page, I have a navigation bar with links to click to navigate to other .aspx pages.   In the master page .cs file, each link gets a click handler.

```
link.Click += navPrimary_Click;

protected void navPrimary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add(SelectedNavItemKeyPrimary, ((LinkButton)sender).Text);
        Session.Add(SelectedNavItemKeySecondary, string.Empty);
        Response.Redirect(((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument);
    }
```

the routes in angular look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }];
```

The test.aspx page loads fine in the browser (lets call it "http://localhost/xyz/abc/test.aspx").  I can click the links in the navigation bar and the browser loads the other .aspx pages correctly.  On the test.aspx page, there is this angular code:

```
<a routerLink="/home">Angular Home</a>
```

When I click the 'Angular Home' link, the angular view shows on the test.aspx page, and the url address in the browser now says "http://localhost/home" instead of "http://localhost/xyz/abc/test.aspx".

Now, when I click any of the navigation bar links, then I get this:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /test.aspx

The url address in the browser now says "http://localhost/test.aspx" instead of "http://localhost/home".

Comment: Any reason why you are mixing 2 different framework into 1? You can't use angular routing for webforms redirect, angular doesn't know anything about your webforms stuff. I'd recommend separating them out angular for client side and api for server side.

Comment: @penleychan thanks for your comment.   I have inherited a web forms project from years ago.  I want to start doing exactly what you suggested:  separate the client side (new Angular code) from the server side.   On the server side, I'll have new REST services that Angular calls separate from the web forms server side code.  But I still have to be able to have Angular and .aspx pages work together in the same application until all of my .aspx pages have been replaced by Angular.